# How to Get Response from Servlet to Android using HttpUrlConnection

Tags: android, servlets, httpurlconnection, server-communication

I tried to get data from servlet but failed. I used HttpUrlConnection class instead of HttpClient or HttpConnection and 'get' method. I can't find What is wrong. Android app didn't failed but they can't get any json string from server. android log, servlet code and android code is here.

and I Really want to know what is SBSetting, ShipBuild and SmartBonding and solve this problem.
Please help me!

```
12-31 15:01:16.279 26003-26625/capston.stol.dangerousplace I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-31 15:01:16.279 26003-26625/capston.stol.dangerousplace I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
12-31 15:01:16.279 26003-26625/capston.stol.dangerousplace I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-3535-332636781: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
12-31 15:01:16.279 26003-26625/capston.stol.dangerousplace I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-31 15:01:16.289 26003-26625/capston.stol.dangerousplace I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
```

This is Servlet Code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class WarningInfoView
 */
@WebServlet("/warning/view")
public class WarningInfoView extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        double xGps = 37.869972;
        double yGps = 127.743389;
        try {
            ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
            Class.forName(sc.getInitParameter("driver"));

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    sc.getInitParameter("url"),
                    sc.getInitParameter("username"),
                    sc.getInitParameter("password"));
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            xGps = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("xcoord"));
            yGps = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("ycoord"));
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT idx,w_count,xcoord,ycoord,title FROM warning_info"
                    + " WHERE (xcoord BETWEEN "
                                +(xGps-0.00447625)+" AND "+(xGps+0.00447625)+ ") AND (" //위도 +-500m
                               +"ycoord BETWEEN "
                                +(yGps-0.055329)+" AND "+(yGps+0.055329)+");"); //경도 +-500m
            JSONObject jsonMain = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();

            while(rs.next()){
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();

                int idx = rs.getInt("idx");
                int w_count = rs.getInt("w_count");
                double xcoord = rs.getDouble("xcoord");
                double ycoord = rs.getDouble("ycoord");
                String title = rs.getString("title");

                jObject.put("idx", idx);
                jObject.put("w_count",w_count);
                jObject.put("xcoord",xcoord);
                jObject.put("ycoord",ycoord);
                jObject.put("title",title);

                jArray.add(0,jObject);
            }
            jsonMain.put("List", jArray);

            System.out.println(jsonMain.toJSONString());
            String json = jsonMain.toJSONString();

            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(json);


        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

And, this is Android Code.

```
    private class SndMyLocReqWarnInfoList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... param){

        String lat = param[0];
        String lng = param[1];
        try {

            Log.e("latlng", lat + ", " + lng);

            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.setProperty("xcoord", lat);
            prop.setProperty("ycoord", lng);
            String encodedString = encodeString(prop);

            URL url = new URL(getString(R.string.MainURL) + getString(R.string.SndMyLocReqWarnInfoList) + encodedString);

            Log.e("URL", url + "");

            HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            try {

                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                Log.e("respCode", responseCode+"");

                if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                    String line = "";
                    String res = "";
                    while((line == br.readLine()) == true){
                        res += line;
                    }

                    Log.e("result json:", res);

                    is.close();
                }

            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("getwilist ", "error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

}

public static String encodeString(Properties params) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(256);
    Enumeration names = params.propertyNames();

    while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = (String) names.nextElement();
        String value = params.getProperty(name);
        sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(name) + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value) );

        if (names.hasMoreElements()) sb.append("&");
    }
    return sb.toString();

}
```

Comment: ' can't get any json string from server. '. Well what does String res contain? You should tell how your code flows.

Comment: {"List":[{"xcoord":37.869972,"idx":3,"title":"sbpark1","ycoord":127.743089,"w_count":0},{"xcoord":37.869072,"idx":2,"title":"sbsb","ycoord":127.743389,"w_count":0},{"xcoord":37.869972,"idx":1,"title":"hello","ycoord":127.743389,"w_count":0}]
}
This is response value of the URL. This AsyncTask send their location to server and receive list of informations(xcoord, ycoord, title, idx, count).

Comment: So you get json from server. Then why are you stating that you don't?

Comment: oh no....Thank you and I'm sorry to bothering you... the problem is... in while loop I write two equals... stupid
`while((line == br.readLine()) == true)`
next to line...

Answer (score 0):

Use [Post Man Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to check you are getting valid response.
I am using following get using httpuurlconnection. please use below and check it.

```
public String sendGet(String apiUrl) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but It still doesn't work.

If  use getInputStream() after getResponseCode(), do you think it make problems?